# Heater blows cold at idle 2007 town / country

Tags: chrysler, heater, town-and-country

I have  a 2007 town / country that blows cold air when at idle.

Comment: Did you try turning the control knob over from blue to red? Sorry ... seriously we'll need more information than this. There are probably *at least* a dozen different reasons this could be happening. Give us some more information about what's going on and we'll be happy to help. You may find some information in the [Help Section](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help) or possibly on our work-in-progress [helping people to figure out what SE is all about](http://meta.mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/1460/helping-our-new-users-make-the-transition)

Comment: @Paulster2 Created : http://meta.mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/1488/1743

Answer (score 1):

Things to check:

- Is the engine fan running slowly at idle? If so, its a sign that it needs replacement.
- Is there a funny smell in the cabin? Refrigerant tends to slowly leak and has a weird smell. Have a friend smell the cabin air in case you got used to the smell (due to driving it all the time).

For more and better help we will need a bit more info.